# How to Show Textarea Content on ClassicEditor CKEditor on Laravel Livewire CKEditor

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

I got stuck on displaying content on Textarea on Livewire CKEditor ClassicEditor. I can show content if only using plain textarea, but the result is not the same if I use CKEditor ClassicEditor. It's empty.
[image]
Here is my textarea code:

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-12" >
    <label for="content" class="box-title">{{ __('Content') }}</label>
    <div class="@error('content') is-invalid @enderror">
        <div wire:ignore>
            <textarea id="content" name="content" class="editor form-control form-control-user" wire:model.defer="content" required autocomplete="content">{{ $content }}</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    @error('content')
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
    @enderror
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript code:

```js
<script>
    ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('#content'))
    .then(editor => {
        editor.model.document.on('change:data', () => {
            @this.set('content', editor.getData());
        })
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
</script>
```

How to solve this?
I got stuck on this case for more than a week, please help?

Comment: I am having same issue here. Any progress on the issue?